# menu with flavicon and label below

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

my target is to recreate this menu here:

 its a flavicon with a label below
[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyi3w.png)

Then i tried in 2 ways both failed:
i am using bootstrap groups

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">




    <div class="btn-group  btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><span class="fas fa-home"></span></button>   <label for="btn">label</label> 
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fa fa-book-open"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="far fa-address-card"></i></button>
      </div>
    
    <p> <p>
    other my try:
    <p>  <p>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
 <div class="btn-group-lg form-group"  >
       <button type="button" id="btn"  class="btn btn-secondary form-control"><span class="fas fa-home"></span></button> 
         <label for="btn">label</label>
    
           <button type="button" id="btn2"  class="btn btn-secondary form-control"><span class="fas fa-home"></span></button> 
         <label for="bt2n">label</label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use the radio button approach from the Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/buttons/

With some styling I'm sure you can use buttons as well, if that's necessary.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><br />
    <input type="radio" name="options1" id="option1" checked>Button text
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fa fa-book-open"></i><br />
    <input type="radio" name="options2" id="option2">Button text
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><br />
    <input type="radio" name="options3" id="option3">Button text
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="far fa-address-card"></i><br />
    <input type="radio" name="options4" id="option4">Button text
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use d-block bootstrap class for fa icon span tag and wrap label inside button like below

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">




    <div class="btn-group  btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><span class="fas fa-home d-block"></span><label for="btn">label</label></button>    
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fa fa-book-open d-block"></i><label for="btn">label</label></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart d-block"></i><label for="btn">label</label></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="far fa-address-card d-block"></i><label for="btn">label</label></button>
      </div>
    
    <p> <p>
    other my try:
    <p>  <p>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

A different way to go would be to use the standard Bootstrap menu layout and include your icons in that.

The advantage to using the normal unordered list is things like screen readers will understand that it's a menu, but a series of buttons could be confusing.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.far, .fa, .fas {
    display: block;
}
.nav-link {
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link, 
.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #940000 !important;
}
</style>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fas fa-home"></span>Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about"><i class="fa fa-book-open"></i>Open</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Cart</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about"><i class="far fa-address-card"></i>Address</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```